# Does the orbital function divided by the volume of a ball decrease?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Cartan-Hadamard manifold, meaning a complete, connected, simply connected Riemannian manifold with non-positive sectional curvature and $\Gamma < Isom(X)$ a discrete group of isometries of $X$. On can define the orbital function as follows

$$ N_{\Gamma}(x,\rho) := \sharp \{ \gamma \in \Gamma \ , \ d(x, \gamma \cdot x) \le \rho \} $$

where $d$ is the distance on $X$ induced by the metric. We will denote by $V(x, \rho)$ the volume of a ball centered at $x$ of radius $\rho$.

All the examples of orbital functions I have in mind (action of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^2$  on the plane, fundamental groups of finite volume hyperbolic manifolds and their abelian covers, convex-cocompact group actions...) satisfy that the following function

$$  \frac{N_{\Gamma}(x, \rho)}{V(x, \rho)} $$

is equivalent when $\rho \to \infty$ to a decreasing function. So that I wondered if this property may be more general. Here is then my question, does the previous property always occur ?

One can relax a bit the previous property as follow.

There exists $\rho_0 \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $\rho_2 \ge \rho_1 \ge \rho_0$ we have :

$$  \frac{N_{\Gamma}(x, \rho_2)}{V(x, \rho_2)} \le C \hspace{0.3cm} \frac{N_{\Gamma}(x, \rho_1)}{V(x, \rho_1)} \ .$$

From the homogeneity that enjoys the orbit $\Gamma \cdot x$, it seems quite natural to me that it actually holds, at least when the group is finitely generated, but I don't know how to get into it.

Does someone has either a reference/an idea toward a proof or a counter example to this ?

Thank you for your reading.